2017 Nissan Note EML light issue
Need some advice  please.
We bought  2017 Nissan Note. A few weeks  later an orange  EML light came on. Took for  diagnostic to Nissan  dealer. Diagnostic identified  that  2 DPF pipes need replacing and  re gen. After the work  they removed the  EML light.
The next day the EML light came back on. Took car back to Nissan.  They are saying  that  everything  is  OK with  car. Used a special  code to remove the EML  light.
Took car home. EML light is back on.
What could  the problem  be with it.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
